# Create an application specific user on windows

Tags: windows, user-accounts, application-launch

I need to create a specific user for an application, and I want to know what kind of user I should create, and best way to use it on current logged user account.

**Context**:

I’m working on a software development. It works on to main environment types: local mode on windows desktop versions, with one windows account logged on the system, and a terminal server mode (TSE) on windows server versions with many users logged on. Users have often low permissions, but the software must execute many task with elevated rights.

**Question**:

To manage authorizations (on folders or whatever), we need to create a specific user for the application, and run the app with this account inside the user session.

I don’t know which type of user I should create, probably not a standard one, as it doesn’t need a desktop environment or possibility to log in as windows session.

Is it possible to create user like MSSQLSERVER (it seems it’s a service account)? Or is there an equivalent to IIS pools for desktop applications?
To use the account inside the application, we planned to use Impersonation. Is this a good choice?

Comment: "I don’t know which type of user I should create" - Just create a new user group with only the permissions that are required, then create add a single user account which you create, to that user group.

Comment: @Ramhound, this is why I need some advices: permissions to add, like type of user (service, task etc), if there is a standard group for that kind of use, best pratices etc.

Comment: You are the best and likey ONLY person, that can determine, what permissions your application needs and does not need

Comment: I'm not sure MSSQLSERVER is actually a real user (would be local) on the system but rather just an instance name identifying that specific SQL Server instance. Just create user and set the permissions accordingly. Another approach would be to use a [Service Account](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548356(v=ws.10).aspx) but it really depends on your software, what you need to do etc. and the user probably needs the permission to logon but not the permission to run interactively, again depended on your application. Having one hard coded account can be quite dangerous.